# Why is my form input not working when I put php code in it? Is there is some syntax error that I am unaware of?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have run into problems in the past with

```
<form action="..." method="post"></form>
```

when I put paragraph or similar html tags within it.  Is there something similar that could cause my form to not be working here?  I am trying to get the submit button to go to "submit.php" upon clicking.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <?PHP
    //Default
    if(!session_id()) session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['x'])) {
    $_SESSION['x'] = 0;
    }
    //Add new button for adding new links
    function addnew($x) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
        if($i !== $x) {
    ?>
    <div align="center">
    <table border=0">
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="keyword[]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="link[]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
            <?PHP
            if($_SESSION['x'] < 1) {
                echo "";
            } else {
                if($i == ($x - 1)) {
                    //submit form here
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>            
                    <?PHP
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </form>
```

The point of all the session checking is to place my submit button on the end of my submit forms.  I am building a simple html input form where when you click a new input button a new input pops up, you can click the button to add as many as you want.  Basically I just need to know why my submit button won't work.

If this doesn't work I may just end up building the submit form ground-up from jquery.

Comment: You're using table based layout and your mingling your PHP with your presentation.

Comment: Can php not be used inside of a table like that?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, I'm just saying that your approach to this problem is fundamentally flawed and a bad design choice. You can do what you're doing, I just don't recommend it.

Comment: Move the `session_start()` code to the top of the file.  You can't have output/HTML before `session_start()`.  You would see this as an error with `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`.

Comment: I will try adjusting that, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @gnarly how would you suggest I change the layout?

Comment: That's a big question, unfortunately too big of a question to answer here. If this is a new project, I recommend using a proper templating system (Twig) or framework such Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about this solution because I can't check if it solves the problem, but try to use echo instead of using `<?php` and `?>` everytime.

```
<?php
echo '<form action="submit.php" method="post">';
    //Default
    if(!session_id()) session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['x'])) {
        $_SESSION['x'] = 0;
    }
    //Add new button for adding new links
    function addnew($x) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
        if($i !== $x) {
            echo '<div align="center">
            <table border=0">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="keyword[]">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="link[]"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';
                if($_SESSION['x'] < 1) {
                    echo "";
                } else {
                    if($i == ($x - 1) && $limit==0) {
                        $limit++;
                        echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>';    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo'</div>
    </form>';
```

**Also, I just read Abra Cadaver comment on your question and I think his solution might solve it as well. I had this problem before and it also caused by `session_start()`.**

Comment: This setup works for removing some clutter from my code, but unfortunately the submit button is still not working.  I might just try to change my entire setup, thanks for the reply

Comment: @gshr11 I really don't think it will make any difference, but try to remove the / at the end of the submit input.

Comment: No luck unforunatley, I think it might have something to do with how I embedded the submit button under the conditional, when I place the button directly in the table it works fine.  The issue I have is that the button shows up for every new input box I create.  The conditional is necessary to limit the button to one occurence

Comment: @gshr11 updated answer, added limit to the submit button amout